# Using chrono, how should time be stored as a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm using Chrono to standardize the usage of timestamps in an application.

Given a timestamp, I would create a timepoint. I'd then convert it to time_t to pass it as a parameter.

`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t (timePoint)`

Should I be passing a timepoint instead? What seems to be best practice?

```
void func(time_t time)
```

or

```
void func(std::chrono::time_point timePoint)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is that unless you have to drop down to the C API (e.g. `time_t`) for compatibility with some other code that uses it, just stay in `<chrono>` (e.g. `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`).  It has better precision, and is a unique type with the semantics "time point" instead of just an integral type.

That is, my vote is:

```
void func(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint);
```

C++20 will bring many facilities to make it easier to work with the `<chrono>` types, and those facilities are prototyped in a free open source library:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Note I slightly altered your suggestion.  `std::chrono::time_point` is a class template, not a type:

```
template<class Clock, class Duration = typename Clock::duration>
    class time_point;
```

I chose `system_clock` as that is the clock that is analogous to the C type `time_t`.  It counts time since since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, except at a higher precision than `time_t` typically does.

And `system_clock::time_point` is a type alias for `time_point<system_clock>` (you could use either).

For a video tutorial on `<chrono>`, see:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Thanks Howard. I must say it is an honor seeing your answer :) looking forward to c++20. Keep up the great work

Comment: It was that cppcon video which lead me down the chrono path :)